# Dual spaces and gradients and subgradients

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Suppose we have some function $f:{\mathbb R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Its gradient is defined as the vector which gives the directional derivative via $(v,\nabla f )=D_{v}f$ for any direction $v$.

Could, or should, we think of $\nabla f$ as something belonging to the dual space of the domain of $f$? And if yes, what is the idea of going about this in this way? In particular are there some geometric ideas involved?

I ran into this idea while learning about subgradients and generalised subgradients, which are defined as functionals on the space of the domain of $f$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where were you learning about subgradients? Was there a book you were reading?

Comment: @littleO https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative#The_subgradient , there is probably  something in references

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think about the derivative is this: 
$$
\tag{1} f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0).
$$ 
The linear function on the right provides a simple but accurate approximation of $f$ near $x_0$.
If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, then $f'(x_0)$ is a real number. If $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, then $f'(x_0)$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.

In the special case that $m = 1$, $f'(x_0)$ is a row vector. If we use the convention (common in optimization) that $\nabla f(x_0)$ is a column vector, then we have $$
\nabla f(x_0) = f'(x_0)^T.
$$

If we prefer to work with linear transformations rather than matrices, then we may choose to define the derivative to be a linear transformation (often denoted $Df(x_0)$)  rather than a matrix. In this approach, equation (1) becomes
$$
\tag{1} f(x) \approx f(x_0) + Df(x_0)(x - x_0).
$$
When $m = 1$, $Df(x_0)$ is the linear functional that maps a vector $\Delta x$ to $\langle \nabla f(x_0), \Delta x \rangle$.

Comment: Right, so then it is a functional on the domain? Subgradients seams to be realated to a subset of elements of this dual, i.e functionals fullfilling certain conditions.

Comment: Why the downvote? Just curious.

Comment: I did not downvote it

Comment: Oh, I know you didn't downvote @user1. I should have addressed my comment to anonymous downvoter. By the way, I don't know that I have a particularly enlightening answer to your previous comment, but if $f$ is convex then a vector $g$ is a subgradient of $f$ at $x_0$ iff $f(x) \geq f(x_0) + \langle g, x- x_0\rangle$ for all $x$. If we prefer to define a subgradient to be a linear functional, we could say a linear functional $g$ is a subgradient of $f$ at $x_0$ iff $f(x) \geq f(x_0) + g(x-x_0)$ for all $x$.

Comment: As far as i know we think of the range or the space we are in as the collum vectors and so if we wanna take scalar products we want to do that with rows. Hence $\nabla f$ is a row. This seams to be very much up for debate tho.

Comment: There are certainly authors who define $\nabla f(x)$ to be a row vector, for example I believe Terence Tao does this in his Analysis II textbook. In optimization, the gradient $\nabla f(x)$ is often defined to be a column vector rather than a row vector. Maybe this is because in optimization we are frequently using gradient descent, and we want to write the gradient descent iteration as $x^{k+1} = x^k - t \nabla f(x^k)$. Since $x^k$ is a column vector, this equation only makes sense as written if $\nabla f(x)$ is a column vector.

Comment: Since I have an optimization background, I follow this convention. So in my mind, I distinguish between $f'(x)$ (which is a $1 \times n$ row vector if $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$), and $\nabla f(x) = f'(x)^T$ (which is a column vector that we use in gradient descent).

Answer (score 1):

As I answered this myself, please upvote if it makes sense!

We have

$f(x)=f(a)+(\nabla f,x-a) + $ Error $=f(a)+f_{x}(x_{1}-a_{1})+f_{y}(x_{2}-a_{2})$+ Error

Hence we can think of the functional as a functional generating the tangetplane by collecting all the directional derivatives.

Now the subgradients are functionals $g$ on the range such that

$f(x)\ge f(a) + g(x-a)=f(a) + y^t(x-a)$

where the second equality follows by Riesz theorem. We thus have functionals such that we are below or equal to the graph in any direction. These must, in analogy with the onedimensonal case be linear subspaces i.e planes for functions in two variables as any functional has as it coordiantes a normal to some plane.

Comment: @littleO I slept on it. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I think this seems to be consistent with my own understanding.

Comment: @littleO I got back to this issue again, tbh I think the right way to think about this is via the pushforward differential. Hence $\nabla f$ acts on a space which is isomorphic  to the domain of $f$ i.e the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at some point. It is just the Jacobian but it does not act on the domain per se but the tanget space(which in this case is the same)

Answer (score 0):

You are right to mention that $\nabla f$ is vector information coded in the dual.

On the level curves $f(x)=a$ for a constant value, we perform a composition $f\circ C:I\to\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ with $f\circ C(t)=f(C(t))$, so  you are going to get that for $x$ which are on the level curve $$f(C(t)=f(x)=a,$$ and $$\nabla f(C(t))\cdot C'(t)=0,$$ by the change rule. And this is the same for all $x\in f^{-1}(a)$.

So you can interpret that the gradient has the components of a vector, in each point in the level set, which is perpendicular to tangent $C'$ at each point $C(t)=x$, at each level curve.

Comment: Cf.  or https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/grad/grad.html or https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Gradient_of_a_Function.tif